# .htaccess, DirectoryIndex does not function normally

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm new to htaccess, and I try to use `DirectoryIndex` to modify the default page for my `img` folder so that when the user try to type my `img` folder, i can re-direct to my home page.

In my .htaccess file of my img folder

```
// my site folder locates in htdocs/lserev
DirectoryIndex /lserev/index.php
```

When I try to type something like `localhost/lserev/img`, I didn't re-direct to my `index.php`, instead, the url address is still `localhost/lserev/img`, but the content of the page is `index.php` without rendering correctly (no image, no css).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Root folder .htaccess file edit and use the RedirectMatch Option. There is no need to have a seperate .htacces file that resides in any other folder for redirects.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/imagefolder/$ http://mydomain/
```

Just to note for anyone who cannot get this to work, you will also need to add the following in the .htaccess file at the top for this Option to work

```
RewriteEngine On
```

and also in the Apache Configuration File make sure the (AllowOverride None) is changed to (All) for the specific web folder or root folder to enable the RewriteEngine to accept options in the .htaccess file.

```
AllowOverride All
```

and last you will need to load the (rewrite) Module to the Apache server. For Linux use the following command. For other Platforms refer to the documentation.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

## ================

## ================

Alternatively To Redirect from any Folder a PHP index page can be just as good to redirect to the home page. This index Page can be placed in any folder you do not wish to be browsed or want to redirect to the home page or any other page.

```
<?php 

header("Location: http://myhomepage.php");

?>
```

## ================

## ================

You can also disable folder browsing by editing the Apache config file and remove indexes. The line may look like this

```
Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

so remove (Indexes) and restart the apache server.

If you try and browse the folders now you will get a (Forbidden) message.

Comment: True if you have hundreds of folders it will be a pain, otherwise just do the index page once and copy and paste it into the other folders you don't want to browsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in an `.htaccess` file & place it within the `lserev/img/` directory on your server:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php  [NC,L,R=301]
```

The `Options -Indexes` disables directory indexing.

Then the `RewriteCond` checks to see if the request URL doesn’t have `.gif`, `.jpg` or `.png` in the URL. And if it doesn’t have those? Well, the next `RewriteRule` comes into play that redirects the request to your `index.php` page.